# R/Shiny: Transpose and add data to Dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, transpose

I'm trying to figure out a way to transpose data and then add that data to a seperate dataframe.

I have

```
Column 1 | Column 2| Column 3
________________________________
Data 1   | Data 2  | Data 3
```

And in a seperate data frame I have

```
actualColumn1| actualColumn2
________________________________
Column 1   | otherData 2   
Column 2   | otherData 2   
Column 3   | otherData 2
```

And want to get to:

```
actualColumn1| actualColumn2|addedData
________________________________
Column 1   | otherData 2 | Data 1  
Column 2   | otherData 2 | Data 2  
Column 3   | otherData 2 | Data 3
```

Since the column names from the first dataframe correspond perfectly to the rows in `actualcolumn1`. I apologize if I didn't explain this very well. I'm still new to R/Shiny and dataframe manipulation.

Comment: Remove pandas ~

Comment: @BENY My Python is showing ;) My apologies!

Comment: R have melt then merge

Comment: Do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format) answer your question?

Comment: `t()` will give you the transpose, but if you are working with data frames, you have to change it back to a data frame. (`t()` will change it to a matrix)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reshape the dataframe to have the 1 observation of 3 variables to 1 variable with 3 observations using `pivot_longer()`, then join to the other dataframe.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>% 
  mutate(x = 1) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -x, names_to = "actualColumn1", values_to = "addedData") %>% 
  select(-x) %>% 
  left_join(x = df2, y = .)

# Joining, by = "actualColumn1"
#    actualColumn1 actualColumn2 addedData
# 1:      Column 1   otherData 2    Data 1
# 2:      Column 2   otherData 2    Data 2
# 3:      Column 3   otherData 2    Data 3
```

Data:

```r
df1 <- data.table::fread("Column 1 | Column 2| Column 3
Data 1   | Data 2  | Data 3   ")

df2 <- data.table::fread("actualColumn1| actualColumn2
Column 1   | otherData 2   
Column 2   | otherData 2   
Column 3   | otherData 2   ")
```

Comment: I think this would do it but i'm having one issue `Warning: Error in : Can't join on `x$id` x `y$id` because of incompatible types.
i `x$id` is of type <double>>.
i `y$id` is of type <character>>.` Is there anyway to convert without adding to much code?

Comment: You need to add snippets of what your actual data is. I guessed based on your question that actualColumn1 in your other data frame contained the same values as the column names of the pretransposed dataframe. Based on your error, clearly they are not? If I am wrong, then you can simply do  `mutate(id = as.double(id))` before piping into the join.

Comment: It is no longer erroring out, but for some reason the "addedData" column is not being added to df2

Comment: Have you assigned the result? `df2 <- df1 %>%... left_join(x=df2, y = .)`